# How to create a contact form using rails that saves to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a contact us style form that saves the info to a database and also sends an email to an admin address. I am rather stuck on how to do this in rails so that the data is saved to the database. I would also like to implement validations and use tdd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Model**

There are several things you need to consider:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :contact, only: [:new, :create], path_names: { new: "" }

#app/models/contact.rb
Class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :name, :email, :message, presence: { message: "You need to fill all the fields!" }
end

#app/controllers/contact_controller.rb
Class ContactController < ApplicationController
    def new 
       @contact = Contact.new
    end

    def create
       @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
       @contact.save
    end
end

#app/views/contact/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @contact do |c| %>
    <%= c.text_field :name %>
    <%= c.text_field :email %>
    <%= c.text_field :message %>
    <%= c.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will give you the ability to create a `contacts` datatable, which you'll be able to create using the [rails migration system](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

--

**Email**

If you want to email the admin of the site, you'll be best doing the following:

```
#app/models/contact.rb
Class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
   after_create :send_email

   private

   def send_email
      ... email code here
   end
end
```

To determine how to send emails, you'll want to [check out this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-send-email.htm)